# Scrape data from site with browser-based Template Engine

Tags: node.js, jsdom

Trying to scrape data from [page](http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2013/colorado-rockies-san-diego-padres-GEeFLlSo/) that templates in browser with a lot of JS. And when playing with **jsdom** can't get any data, maybe page doesn't have enough time to load or render.
How to scrape data in this case: use timer or download all page by [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request)

```
jsdom.env({
  url: link,
  scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  done: function (errors, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    var date = $('.date').text();
    console.log(date);
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe PhantomJS can do what you want, as it's a headless browser. request will not be able to do it because it simply downloads the page, and I didn't know jsdom was able to execute page's JS :)

Comment: +1 to PhantomJS, here you have a example to use it with JQuery http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/534-how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-phantomjs-and-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague of mine has a PhantomJS-based project doing just that: https://github.com/vmeurisse/phantomCrawl.

He has a simple example that looks a lot like your snippet:

```
'use strict';

var PhantomCrawl = require('./src/PhantomCrawl');

var urls = [];

urls.push('http://www.bing.com');
var ptc = new PhantomCrawl({
    urls: urls,
    nbThreads: 4,
    crawlerPerThread: 4,
    maxDepth: 1
});
```

`urls` is the list of urls to crawl.

`nbThreads` is the number of instances of PhantomJS launched.

`crawlerPerThread` is the number of pages crawled in parallel per instance of PhantomJS.

`maxDepth` is the number of times the currently crawled page follows links present in the page.